# Bitbucket..Yaml syntax error regarding to the pipeline

Tags: docker, yaml, bitbucket

```
version: "3"
services:
    rabbit-api-dev:
    image: __ECR_ADDRESS__
    ports:
      - "0:5000"
    entrypoint: /usr/local/bin/poetry
```

Does anyone know if there is an error in the yaml syntax?
I am trying everything to fix the error, but failed.
The exact error message is as below..
"Error unmarshaling yaml data from Compose file.
could not find expected ':'"

1st correcting...

```
version: "3.8"
services:
    rabbit-api-dev:
     image: __ECR_ADDRESS__
     ports:
       - "0:5000" 
    entrypoint: /usr/local/bin/poetry
```

Comment: `image:` and `ports:` need to be indented one step more.  `entrypoint:` should probably be removed (the Dockerfile should have a `CMD` and you want to use that).  The first `ports:` number probably shouldn't be 0 and that might cause the specific error. I don't think `__ECR_ADDRESS__` on its own is a valid image name (is it replaced with something else by a script?).  You probably want `version: '3.8'` and not `3` (implying `3.0`).

Comment: @DavidMaze
Thanks for the reply
I corrected the syntax as you said..

version: "3.8"
services:
    rabbit-api-dev:
     image: `__ECR_ADDRESS__`  (this will be replaced by a valid script)
     ports:
      - "0:5000" (
    entrypoint: /usr/local/bin/poetry (this is a docker compose file)

I will try and let you know again!